# Name this concept: Comparing equal sized vectors vs. comparing features

Tags: terminology, vector-spaces, signal-processing

If you obtain a vector by taking $n$ discrete samples over some underlying function, then it's easy to compare that vector with another of the same size.  With a bunch of $n$-dimensional vectors, you can do interesting analysis like PCA.  However, if all your vectors have different dimensionality, such as a bunch of images taken of (potentially) the same object at different resolutions, the problem is trickier.  In computer vision, they often use a feature transform (such as SIFT) that will provide a comparison metric for the two vectors.

Is there a name for the problem of finding a transformation of a subspace from one vector that is closely aligned with a different transformation of a different subspace from another vector?  E.g., matching a single word between two speakers when the word is embedded within a sentence; or finding an image of a car at different resolutions embedded in two different images.

Comment: You might want to ask this on astronomy.stackexchange.com.  I think they do something similar to align sequences of images in order to get an enhanced composite image.